# Capturing inner string in lark using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, lark-parser

Ok, so, this is probably a bit convoluted solution and I should probably use something simple, but it is what is.

I have a huge text I want to parse using python's lark and I'm piecing together certain parts, and now I'm trying to get the text within the quotes.

Using regex that would be something like:

```
([\"\'])(.*)(\1)
```

- capture first quote
- capture all
- until you capture the last quote that is the same as first

However, adding that to Lark grammar, for instance like this:

```
grammar = r"""
start: contained_string

contained_string: quoted | parenthesis | braces | brackets

quoted      : /([\"\'])(.*)(:\1)/
parenthesis : "(" CONT_STRING+ ")"
braces      : "{" CONT_STRING+ "}"
brackets    : "[" CONT_STRING+ "]"

CONT_STRING: /[\w.,!?:\- ]/
"""
```

And test it out on a list like this:

```
samples = ['"sample"', "'sam'ple'", """'samp"le'"""]
```

I get these as outputs:

```
"sample"
'sam'ple'
'samp"le'
```

Which is ok, it doesn't get tripped the extra quote, either the same type or different. But it keeps the outer quotes. Now usually I could specify that I want the second group from the captured ones, but I'm not sure how to do it within lark like this.

Comment: If you just want to remove the outermost quotes, you might be able to get away with `str.strip('"')` or `str.strip("'")` depending on what type of quotation mark the given string starts with

Comment: There currently is not way builtin into lark to accomplish this. You will need to reparse the string with the corresponding regex, or do some simplified postprocessing.

Comment: Why do you have `:` in `(:\1)`? If you meant to make a non-capture group, it should be `(?:\1)`

Comment: @Barnar - ah, yes, it remained from a non-capture group, sorry.

Comment: @Megaling - yeah, I was afraid of that. Well, I guess I'll do it with transformer. Thanks.